# Short Description and long description are not responsive on product page of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, html, rwd

I am currently facing an issue with the responsiveness of Magento 2 product page. My descriptions are passing the browser screen toward the right side. They are showing up like this in the attached image. Please take a look and let me know if anyone can help me with this issue.

Thank you.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below css?

```
.product.attribute.overview{
    .value{
        p{
            word-break: break-all;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```